# Migrate from Outlook 2007 (Vista) to Entourage 2008 (Mac / Snow Leopard)

Tags: windows, macos, mac, microsoft-outlook-2007, entourage

Is there a straightforward way to migrate all **email-related "stuff"** (mailboxes, settings, contacts, calendar, etc.) from a PC running Vista & Outlook 2007 to a Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Entourage 2008?

Not sure if it's relevant, but the email accounts are all POP; if the mail was IMAP, at least part of the project would be easier.

I've found a bunch of 12-step procedures using Thunderbird as a "middleman" and some other involved plans, but they seem unnecessarily complex.  I keep feeling that there must be some ridiculously easy procedure or tool, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing Microsoft provides that makes this straightforward, the best thing is to use a 3rd party tool that is design to do it.  This is a great blog for anyone who has to support Entourage and has a few suggestions on 3rd party tools but I have not used them: http://www.entourage.mvps.org/import_export/pst.html

Now not to get off topic but I would advise if you dont have a critical reason to use Entourage, DONT DO IT!  I was part of the team at LinkedIn that help them move to Exchange 2010 and support the users with the switch, which was supporting Entourage.  And it was a PITA, and even they knew it.  They could not switch to Mail.app because of a bug in 10.6 at the time but as soon as that was resolved they started to switch to that.  Now MS hopes to bring Outlook to the Mac this might fix things, but for now what you are describing I think you are better off going to use anything else.

Comment: Zuhaib - thanks for answering -- actually, it wasn't for me (Gmail / web interface all the way for me....) - it was for a colleague who moved to the Mac & has been using Outlook for at least 10 years.  I've never been a fan of the MS email programs, but all the companies I consult for seem to use Outlook (also for meetings, etc...)

Comment: Outlook is actually a very good product, nothing really does that good of a job.  It also helps that MS pretty much has it set up to work from top to bottom when you have Exchange, AD, Windows and Outlook.  Gmail is close with its web stuff, but Zimbra has a long way to go before it can challenge MS.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't intend to answer my own question, but just in case anyone else is unfortunate enough to be in a similar situation...

I ended up using the [O2M program](http://www.littlemachines.com/) ($10) from Little Machines.  Even though the website looks like it's from 1997, the program did exactly what it was supposed to.  Over 30,000 emails, 600 contacts, and God knows what else was transferred w/o any problems.

Even though I was hoping for a free & easy solution (those 2 often co-exist), in this case, it was the best $10 I (actually, someone else) spent.

Answer (score 0):

I just used [02M](http://www.littlemachines.com/) to perform this same task.

VERY slow... but got the job done.

Now trying to figure out notes =.

> O2M may be the fastest way to move your Windows® Outlook® email, contacts, and calendar appointments from your PC to your Macintosh® computer! (1) Just fire up O2M on your Windows PC, pick the Outlook folders you want to export, choose the filtering options you want to use, and click Start — O2M does the rest, automatically exporting your Outlook data into portable files you can import directly into your Apple® Mail, Address Book, iCal, Microsoft Entourage, or other Macintosh-compatible programs. Back up all of your PC's email and email attachments to your Apple! Copy your Outlook contacts from work to home and vice-versa! Migrate all of your calendar appointments from your old PC to your new Mac! The possibilities are endless!

Comment: Did you get the notes working?